# Android Leanback : how to keep selected row centered vertically on the screen

Tags: android, gridview, leanback

I have a `DetailsSupportFragment()` screen in which I've implemented 4 rows. When I scroll between the rows, it always stays on top of the screen. I would like the selected row to be centered vertically on the screen (even the last row).

I've implemented this but the last row is not scrolling smoothly (a bit jumpy).

```
 rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.setOnChildSelectedListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            val childCount = rowsAdapter.size()
            
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignment = WINDOW_ALIGN_HIGH_EDGE
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent =
                    WINDOW_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
            }
            in 1 until childCount - 1 -> {
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignment = WINDOW_ALIGN_BOTH_EDGE
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent =
                    WINDOW_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
            }
            childCount - 1 -> {
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignment = WINDOW_ALIGN_NO_EDGE
                rowsSupportFragment.verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent =
                    20f
            }
        }
    }`
```

Is there a better way to achieve the desired result in a more clean way?
Thanks in advance !

M A